# Google Maps re-opening the modal issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I know this question has already been asked earlier but my scenario is little different. I too had the problem in displaying Google Map in the modal then I found the solution here i.e to call the resize function on map so that it can be shown in the modal. It exactly worked fine. But only for the first time i.e when I open the modal once it shows the map fine but when I close and open it again then it again renders partially.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#view-on-map').on('click', function () {
    initialize();
});
function initialize()
{
    var latitude = $("#latitude").text();
    var longitude = $("#longitude").text();
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("seller-map")
            , mapProp);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

What I am doing wrong? I would also like to point out that I am only creating the map when modal is loaded (as demonstrated in the code), I tried to load it on window.load event and then call the resize function on that when modal is opened but that did not work. My markup uses [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal) and not the bootstrap one.
Looking for help. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not triggering the resize event when the modal is shown but when `#view-on-map` is clicked.

Simple Modal has a `onShow` function:

> The callback function used after the modal dialog has opened. Useful for binding events or any other actions you might want to perform after the modal dialog elements have been displayed. If you are including another plugin (TinyMCE, DatePicker, etc.) in a modal dialog, this is where you want to initialize that plugin.

1. Remove the resize trigger from the `initialize` function.
2. Load the map (initialize)
3. Create the modal and set the `onShow` callback to trigger the map resize

*Example:*

```
$("#element-id").modal({

    onShow: function () {

        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    }
});
```

*Note:*

Your `map` variable needs to be global.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing it out. I did exactly what you said and its working now. 1+ and I accept the answer.